# after_rollback not triggered when model.with_lock is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I have a project build using Rails 4.2.5

When I have my code like

```
@job = Job.find(1)
update_job(attrs)
```

If any method is before_* returns false after_rollback is called but when I change my code to

```
@job = Job.find(1)
@job.with_lock('FOR UPDATE NOWAIT') do
  update_job(attrs)
end
```

after_rollback is not called. I am using postgresql 9.3 and 9.5 for my database.

Above code inside with_lock block seems to be working with 9.4.4